# Removing/Hiding search bar from TableSelectDialog

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I am using a TableSelectDialog to display a table with 5-6 columns in it. I want to remove or hide the default search bar and also to remove the cancel button from its footer and to add a custom 'OK' button.

```
    <core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
        <TableSelectDialog noDataText="No Indent Found" confirm="handleClose" items="{path: 'Create>/Status'}">
            <ColumnListItem id="item0_1560778285375">
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{Create>IndentNo}" id="indenNo"/>
                    <Text text="{Create>So_no}" id="soNo"/>
                    <Text text="{Create>Vehicle}" id="truckNo"/>
                    <Text text="{Create>Status}" id="status"/>
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
            <columns>
                <Column id="column0" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <header>
                        <Label design="Bold" text="Indent No" id="label8"/>
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="column1" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <header>
                        <Label text="Sales Order No." id="label10" design="Bold"/>
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="column2" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <header>
                        <Label text="Vehicle No." id="label9" design="Bold"/>
                    </header>
                </Column>
                <Column id="column3" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                    <header>
                        <Label text="Status" id="statuscolumn" design="Bold"/>
                    </header>
                </Column>
            </columns>
        </TableSelectDialog>
    </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the basic Dialog instead.

The same events are available here (partially with different names) since the TableSelectDialog ist just a convenience control for the Dialog with some extras like the search bar.

```
    <core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog>
        <content>
            <Table mode="SingleSelectMaster" itemPress=".handleClose" noDataText="No Indent Found" items="{path: 'Create>/Status'}">
                <ColumnListItem id="item0_1560778285375">
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{Create>IndentNo}" id="indenNo"/>
                        <Text text="{Create>So_no}" id="soNo"/>
                        <Text text="{Create>Vehicle}" id="truckNo"/>
                        <Text text="{Create>Status}" id="status"/>
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
                <columns>
                    <Column id="column0" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <header>
                            <Label design="Bold" text="Indent No" id="label8"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                    <Column id="column1" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <header>
                            <Label text="Sales Order No." id="label10" design="Bold"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                    <Column id="column2" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <header>
                            <Label text="Vehicle No." id="label9" design="Bold"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                    <Column id="column3" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                        <header>
                            <Label text="Status" id="statuscolumn" design="Bold"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
            </Table>
        </content>
        <beginButton>
            <Button text="OK" press=".onPressButton"/>
        </beginButton>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Please note that you have to close the dialog manually inside the handleClose/onPressButton function.

---

If you want to keep the TableSelectDialog, you can access the content, the custom header and the buttons of the Dialog as described in the API for the [Dialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog).